# Best C# Profiler?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, profiler

Recently I used RedGate ANTS profiler which seems pretty good, but the application I tried to profile was crashing due to DivideByException, where as running in inside Visual Studio was fine for both debug and release.

Are there other/better C# profilers that you know of?