# Good Websites/Blogs/Books to know about Memory Efficient C# Programming

Tags: c#, performance, memory-management

Based on a [Memory Efficient Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404615/memory-efficient-programming) question on StackOverflow ..... I want to know about Memory Efficient C# Programming.... Any good Websites/Blogs/Books to know about Memory Efficient C# Programming.....

**EDIT:**

Some tips how to write Memory Efficient C# Programming....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Maoni Stephen's blo](http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/)g has a lot of details on the inner workings of the .NET garbage collector.

It doesn't give explicit tips on how to optimize your code, but knowing how the GC works, will help you make the right decisions in many cases.

You may also want to check [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343374/reducing-memory-usage-of-net-applications/1343394#1343394), as it deals with reducing memory usage of .NET applications.

Answer (score 3):

[Rico Mariani's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/) is good for general performance, although it's not updated terribly frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Along with Websites/Blogs/Books, you should consider Profiler tools too, that will show you the problems in real time...

this post [Best C# Profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612711/best-c-profiler) discusses the tools in detail.