# Any ASP.Net benchmark tool?

Tags: .net, asp.net, open-source, benchmarking

I would like to measure the performance of the .Net application, especially web application in ASP.Net when running in the server.

I need to know any benchmark tool enable for me to know my source code can be optimize.
As long as the benchmark tool can be helping me optimize the performance of the website.

Any recommendation for getting a benchmark tool just measuring .Net?
Please kindly list out commercial and free application or any open source benchmark tool.

Comment: http://www.redgate.com/, ANTS - good product. 2008 / 2010 have profilders in the larger versions of the tool. Plenty of others around - did you try google?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-profilers-out-there
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612711/best-c-profiler

Comment: @tanascius: not really duplicates since the OP is asking specifically for profilers suited to ASP.NET, but yeah, a bit of research never hurts!

Answer (score 5):

I know of a great commercial product: [Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/code_profiling.htm) from Red-gate. Easy to use, detailed, though unfortunately not free.

There is also [EQATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler), which is cheaper (even free for personal use!), but I have no experience in using it.

Comment: Ants is well worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains dotTrace and Redgate ANTS

Answer (score 1):

Well, [dotTrace Profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) is really good. For load testing you could go with [jMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)

Answer (score 1):

I can personally recommend [EQATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler). Primarily because it's *sufficient* and *free*.

See also: [Profiling ASP.NET websites with EQATEC Profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378617/profiling-asp-net-websites-with-eqatec-profiler)

But bear in mind that time spent inside your .NET code isn't the only influence on the performance of your website.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/ helps a lot to optimise e.g. transfer/markup issues. Under normal circumstances, your peak load is likely to be bottlenecked by bandwidth long before it's bottlenecked by processor time.

Comment: yslow is a really great way to learn the point to point performance improvements you need to make. +1